# Jinja template parses variable as literal string

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm having a problem where Jinja is treating a variable I'm passing to it as a literal string, which screws up the URL routing work done by Flask.

`app.py` - each "course" has its designated URL, as shown by `/course/<name>`.

```
@app.route("/course/<name>")
@login_required
def course(name):
    collection = mongo.db.courses
    course = collection.find_one({"name": name})
    return render_template("course.html", course=course)
```

`profile.html` - These "courses" will be displayed on the `profile.html` page, and they should have `href` tags that lead them to the appropriately rendered `course.html` page.

**Attempt #1:** I tried passing in `{{ course }}` into the `name` parameter, but the URL was messed up as Jinja treated it as a string altogether.

```
{% for course in courses %}
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <a href="{{ url_for('course', name='{{ course }} }}">{{ course }}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Attempt #2:** I tried setting up a Jinja variable and passing that to the `href` tag, but this did not work as well.

```
{% for course in courses %}
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        {% set url = url_for('course', name="{{ course }}") %}
        <a href="{{ url }}">{{ course }}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I dynamically generate new `href` tags for each `course` variable without having Jinja treat the `href` tags as a literal string?

Comment: what do you mean by "messed up" ? What does the generated html look like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{` begins a block of Python code. Things you do inside it follow Python behavior rules, not those of Jinja. You are passing the value `{{ course }}` as `name` to `url_for`. Just use `course` as a variable.

```
{{ url_for('course', name=course.name) }}
```